# How to remove closing parenthesis using patIndex in t-sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex, t-sql

Below is the select I am using to test my patindex. I am trying to remove all special characters but the result set that comes back is like below. Essentially there are some negative numbers with accounting formatting. I need to remove this formatting and have it just be numbers ($102.00).

```
Sql:
[
0.00,
$102.00)]
select  cast(rtrim(ltrim(Replace([Amount],SUBSTRING([Amount],patindex('%[^0-9]%',[Amount]),1),'') ) )as varchar) from Temp2
```

Does anyone know how to remove that closing `)`? I have tried a bunch of regex but I just cant get it to go away.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: my apologies. I am using Sql Server I start with `[$0.00,($25.00)]`
I get the above. 
I need it to look like `[0.00,25.00]`

I have tried a patindex of `'%[()]%'` or this `'%[\(\)%]'` which only removes the first one. and if I flip it, it only removes the closing parenthesis but not the opening one. And a bunch of other combinations.

Comment: Tell us, the Database, is it SQL Server or mySQL or something else.
Show us, what you have, what you need and what you have done.

Comment: @SrinikaPinnaduwage added a few edits hope that helps. I googled reg expressions as well but for the most part people only want whats inside parathesis's not removing the parathesis's so google was not much help.

Comment: You mean, your data is ` [$0.00,($25.00)]` and You need to return `[0.00,25.00]` ?

Comment: @SrinikaPinnaduwage correct

Answer (score 0):

You can just use Replace 3 times to remove the unwanted characters.

```
Declare @s varchar(100)
Select @s = '[$0.00,($25.00)]'
Select @s as original,  Replace(Replace(Replace(@s,'$',''),'(',''),')','') as cleaned
```

If you need to apply that to a column (ex. Amount) in a table , instead of @s, use that column name in a SQL query

```
Select ...., Replace (.... <<Amount>> ) from yourTable
```

Here is the [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=771f4b2bc8241373a66f0df4b81faf7b)